# How to alphabetically sort a list of options in Vue.js / Buefy form?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

Currently I display a list of hotels for each city in a Vue.js / Buefy form using:

```
 <option
   :value="h['@attributes'].Name"
   v-for="h in cities[form.cities[i].index].Hotels.Hotel"
   :key="cities[form.cities[i].index].Hotels.Hotel.Name"
   v-if="isArray(form.cities[i].index)"
   v-text="h['@attributes'].Name"></option>
```

What should I add to sort them alphabetically? I'm at loss, as I don't know Vue / Buefy so well and I'm modifying a code somebody else wrote.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand what your code is doing so that you know where you need to make changes.
Your loop `v-for` is iterating over your array `cities[form.cities[i].index].Hotels.Hotel` (the naming seems odd to me).

Within this array, there is a key `@attributes` which holds an object with a key `Name`, which is probably what you want to use for sorting.

Normally I would go with computed properties for these things but since you have the array based on a parameter (`form.cities[i].index`) I am not sure that would work so easily. So instead you can use a method to get a sorted version of your array. In your Vue instance, add the following to the "methods" property:

```
methods: {
    sortedHotels: function(hotels) {
        tmp = this.hotels.slice(0);
        tmp.sort(function(a,b) {
             return (a['@attributes'].Name > b['@attributes'].Name) ? 1 : ((b['@attributes'].Name> a['@attributes'].Name) ? -1 : 0);
        });
        return tmp;
    },
},
```

Then, instead of looping through the normal array, you loop through the result of the function call of that array:

```
 <option
     :value="h['@attributes'].Name"
     v-for="h in sortedHotels(cities[form.cities[i].index].Hotels.Hotel)"
     :key="cities[form.cities[i].index].Hotels.Hotel.Name"
     v-if="isArray(form.cities[i].index)"
     v-text="h['@attributes'].Name"></option>
```